# How to Sort Two Columns by Descending Order in Pandas?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe `df` consisting of two columns `ID` and `Date`:

```
ID    Date
4    1/1/2008
3    1/1/2007
2   9/23/2010
2    6/3/1998
2    1/1/2001 # Note this date should be before "6/3/1998" for ID# 2
1   4/30/2003
```

I want to sort `df` by `ID` and `Date` in descending order (largest --> smallest), but this seems not working when I tried the following script:

```
print df.sort_values(by=["ID", "Date"], ascending=["False", "False"])
```

The output should in this descending order:

```
ID    Date
4    1/1/2008
3    1/1/2007
2   9/23/2010
2    1/1/2001 
2    6/3/1998
1   4/30/2003
```

Any idea how can I sort the date in the correct descending order?

Comment: shouldn't it be `df.sort_values(["ID","Date"], ascending=[False,False])`? i.e. bools not strings, what you did caused the strings to be evaluated as `True` boolean values

Comment: Not sure if this is useful. But worth a try. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html

Answer (score 8):

You will first need to convert type of Date column from String to Date.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

Now you can use **df.sort_values**

```
print df.sort_values(by=["ID", "Date"], ascending=[False, False])
```

**Output :**

```
   ID       Date
0   4 2008-01-01
1   3 2007-01-01
2   2 2010-09-23
4   2 2001-01-01
3   2 1998-06-03
5   1 2003-04-30
```

In your code, for ascending argument you are passing string `"False"` , but it should be bool `False`